# How to use new-smbshare with Powershell 3.0 on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I installed Windows Management Framework 3.0 on a Windows 7 machine and tried to use the New-SMBShare cmdlet but when I ran get-command new-smb*, no cmdlets were found. How can I use this new cmdlet in Windows 7 along with any other new cmdlets?

Answer (score 11):

The SMB commands (and several other modules) are specific to Windows 8 and Server 2012.  You can use them from Windows 7 via remoting, but they do not target Windows 7 or Server 2008 R2.

The SMB commands target a new WMI namespace (ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/SMB) that does not exist on earlier versions of the OS.